# CSS Width auto and float left - Allow to overflow

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-float, layer

I've got a container `div` which has property `width: auto;`. This container has children elements which have property `float: left;`. The normal behaviour is to align all the elements continously until one element overflows the container `div`. In that case, that child element will be placed under the other children elements. I'm trying to force children elements to expand container `div` even if it overflows. I want all the children elements to be aligned.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Can you add an example of the HTML markup (preferably using the snippet tool in the editor's menu bar... ctrl-M)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since float elements do not increase parent's width you probably need to make them `display: inline-block` then you can add `white-space: nowrap` to the parent. `display: inline-block` is also useful if you need to use non-transparent background for the parent.

```css
.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.second.container {
  display: inline-block;
}
.container > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: firebrick;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="second container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```